# How do I randomize multiple unordered lists within a randomized ordered list?

Tags: javascript, html, list, random

I'm trying to make a test with randomized questions(randomize the ordered list) that contain randomized answers(randomize the unordered lists). I can get the ordered list to randomize, but I can only get one unordered list to randomize. The code only randomizes the first unordered list it finds. I would like to randomize all the unordered lists. Any help is appreciated.

```
<ol>
<li>What are the three main areas of the Standard User Interface?
  <ul type="none">
    <li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="0" />A. Header, Banner, Frame, Application Window</li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="0" />B. Content Frame, Homepage, Form </li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="1" />C. Application Navigator, Banner Frame, Content Frame </li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="0" />D. None of the above</li>
  </ul>
</li>

<li>In the User interface, what is the gray toolbar called which allows you to add bookmarks?<br/>

  <ul type="none">
    <li><input type="radio" name="g2" value="0" />A. Gauge</li><br />
    <li><input type="radio" name="g2" value="1" />B. Edge</li><br />
    <li><input type="radio" name="g2" value="0" />C. Remedy</li><br />
    <li><input type="radio" name="g2" value="0" />D. Banner</li><br />
  </ul><br/>
</li>

<li>What can be captured in an update set?<br/>

  <ul type="none">
    <li><input type="radio" name="g3" value="0" />A. Modified CI Rules</li><br />
    <li><input type="radio" name="g3" value="1" />B. Business Rules</li><br />
    <li><input type="radio" name="g3" value="0" />C. Scheduled Jobs</li><br />
    <li><input type="radio" name="g3" value="0" />D. None of the above</li><br />
  </ul>
</li>

<li>What should you always do before you commit an update set?<br/>

  <ul type="none">
    <li><input type="radio" name="g4" value="1" />A. Preview</li><br />
    <li><input type="radio" name="g4" value="0" />B. Merge</li><br />
    <li><input type="radio" name="g4" value="0" />C. Ignore</li><br />
    <li><input type="radio" name="g4" value="0" />D. All of the above</li><br />
  </ul>
</li>

<li>Which of the following is a Business Rule best pratice?<br/>

  <ul type="none">
    <li><input type="radio" name="g5" value="1" />A. Make business rules small and specific</li><br />
    <li><input type="radio" name="g5" value="0" />B. Use of conditions is not necessary</li><br />
    <li><input type="radio" name="g5" value="0" />C. Global business rules should be used</li><br />
    <li><input type="radio" name="g5" value="0" />D. None of the above</li><br />
  </ul>
</li>

<li>Which of the following is a Client Script best practice?<br/>

  <ul type="none">
    <li><input type="radio" name="g6" value="0" />A. Use hard coded data</li><br />
    <li><input type="radio" name="g6" value="0" />B. Maximize server lookup</li><br />
    <li><input type="radio" name="g6" value="1" />C. Do not use g_form.getReference()</li><br />
    <li><input type="radio" name="g6" value="0" />D. All of the above</li><br />
  </ul>
 </li>

 <li>Which of the following are debugging features?<br/>


  <ul type="none">
    <li><input type="radio" name="g7" value="0"/>A. Debug Business Rule</li><br />
    <li><input type="radio" name="g7" value="0"/>B. Javascript</li><br />
    <li><input type="radio" name="g7" value="1"/>C. A and B</li><br />
    <li><input type="radio" name="g7" value="0"/>D. None of the above</li><br />
  </ul>
</li>


</ol>
```

Here is my randomization code:

```
var ol = document.querySelector('ol');
temp = ol.cloneNode(true); 

for (var i = temp.children.length; i--; ){
    temp.appendChild( temp.children[Math.random() * i |0] );

    ul.parentNode.replaceChild(temp, ol); 
}

var ul = document.querySelector('ul');
temp = ul.cloneNode(true); 

for (var i = temp.children.length + 1; i--; ){
 temp.appendChild( temp.children[Math.random() * I |0] );

    ul.parentNode.replaceChild(temp, ul); 
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to randomize the list?

Comment: Side note:  Pretty bad practice if you randomize them and "All of the above" is third on the list.  Would that include the fourth choice or not?  Plus, aren't you going to then have A/B/C/D out of order?  And then how do you get answers like "A and B" if you don't know which ones are going to be labeled those letters?

Comment: This is not complete there will be like 50 questions for now im just trying to figure out how randomize a bunch of lists, and i posted my code that i have to randomize.

Comment: In your first `for` loop you reference variable `ul`, instead of `ol`, which is already defined at that point.

Comment: If you use the radio button values like that the people taking the test will be able to lookup the correct answer from the inspector! :P

Comment: Also, I think you are doing the `for` loops wrong, remember: `for(init; condition; final)` init is run at before the first loop, condition is checked before each loop, final is run after each loop.

Comment: You realise, though, that randomising the answers will be a problem for "None of the above", right? :)

Comment: Why are you using a `<ul>` for the answers, when you're explicitly assigning an order to them in the text ('A', 'B', 'C'...), which will be out-of-order on randomising the answer-lists. Just use an `<ol>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.querySelector()` works for the `ol` element because there is only one.  To capture the `ul`s use `querySelectorAll` and loop through value of same.  There is also a problem in that the parent nodes of `ol` and `ul` get lost.  The `parentNode.replaceChild...` statements have to come after, not within, the `for` loops.  In the loop over the `querySelectorAll` value, the parent node has to be backed up; see [setting parent node in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12957267/948073)

```
    var ol = document.querySelector('ol');
    temp = ol.cloneNode(true);

    for (var i = temp.children.length; i--;) {
        temp.appendChild(temp.children[Math.random() * i | 0]);

    }
    ol.parentNode.replaceChild(temp, ol); 

    var ul = document.querySelectorAll('ul'), parent;
    console.log("found " + ul.length + " ul's");
    for (var k = ul.length-1; k >= 0; k--) {
        parent = ul[k].parentNode;
        temp = ul[k].cloneNode(true);

        for (var i = temp.children.length + 1; i--;) {
            temp.appendChild(temp.children[Math.random() * i | 0]);

        }
        parent.replaceChild(temp, ul[k]);
    }
```

Comment: Ah i see, thank you so much i would make sense to put the replaceChild after everything.  Also did not know about the querySelectorAll() method.